# How to test ads if AdView failed to load 3

Tags: android, admob, adview

I use AdViews in my app in almost every activity.

The xml im using is:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/Banner_Ads"
    ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:gnt_template_type="@layout/gnt_small_template_view" />
```

I did every thing I could to test it by either using Test ID for the ads or by setting TestDeviceID and everything works good.

How can I be sure that it will work with real ads? when i did a single check of my app before distribution it gives me `ad failed to load : 3`.

Yes, I read that it can happen if I created ad unit recently and that it might might take time or that it means that my code is correct but there are no ads. But what does it means no ads? isnt AdView meant to be for ads?

Thank you

Comment: As long as the test ad work with you, don't worry, the real ads will work either, the real ads will never appear in the debug mode, it's show in the release mode only, **IMPORTANT : DO NOT TEST WITH YOUR REAL ADS**, it will cause invalid traffic issue,

Comment: Of course, only with setTestDeviceIds I tried